# problem in gridview control of user control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, hide

My problem is I am setting the datasource from parent page.But if I set disable to certain columns of gridview the event of the controls inside those disabled column template gets fired. Like I have a checkbox in one column, if disable that column from parent page while data binding the check_checked event is being fired. 
here my code- **user control aspx**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exclude Null" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Exclude Null
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkExNull" OnCheckedChanged="chkExNull_OnCheckedChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**.cs file of parent**

```
GridView gvCondition = (GridView)ucCondition.FindControl("gvCondition");
    gvCondition.DataSource = ConditionFieldCollection;
    gvCondition.Columns[5].Visible = false;
    gvCondition.Columns[6].Visible = false;
    gvCondition.Columns[7].Visible = false;
    gvCondition.Columns[8].Visible = false;
    gvCondition.DataBind();
```

**What should I do, and is there any other way through which I can hide some of the columns of grid view control of user control??**

Comment: Try hiding the columns after data binding, plus the event you are showing is a check changed event, which is only fired when clicked on, so is the issue the column isn't hiding correctly, or are there other events firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your `DataBind()`. write this:

```
gvCondition.DataBound += new EventHandler(gvwCondition_DataBound);
```

and write in that method, the code to hide the columns.

Hope that helps.